# c++ variable reassignment gets ignored by code

Tags: c++, variables, int, variable-assignment

I am not a professional programmer but after getting some experience in easy languages like python or matlab, I need to make a little program in C++. For this I try to read user input until the user inputs something sensible - however, this loop never terminates due to my control variable (test2) never being reassigned, even though the corresponding code block is entered. Let me explain in detail:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

int test2; //variable to stay 1 until user has entered suitable input
string input2[2]; //storage for input strings

int MinimalTest() {
  test2 = 1; //control variable is set one
  cout << "Enter a string." << endl;
  do {
     //we will enter a string at least once, and we exit this loop only when the input is suitable
      std::string line; //complicated input part - a simple getline() command led to weird behaviour 
      std::getline(std::cin, line);
      std::stringstream linestream(line);
      linestream >> input2[i];
      cout << "input: " << input2[i] << " test: " << test2 << "input bool: " << input2[i].empty() << endl; //this is just for troubleshooting

      if (input2[i].empty()) {
        //if the user entered an empty string, he needs to do it again
          cout << "Your string is empty. Please enter a valid string (non-empty)." << endl;
      }
      else {
        //if he entered a valid string, we can continue with the next input
          cout << "I am here." << endl; //This is for trouble shooting. This code block is entered and executed since this gets printed.
          test2 = 0;// this gets ignored for some reason. Hence, the loop never terminates.
      }
  }(while (test2 = 1);
}
```

So the first loop never terminates. Test2 never gets reassigned to 0, even though the else command is executed. This boggles my mind tbh - it is just a simple assignment operator on an int. Possible output looks like this (Note how I still got a second problem: strings with a space inside get cut off. I would appreciate any feedback on that as well, even though I try to trouble shoot one thing at a time and this post is not aimed at this problem):

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48bQk.png)

Thank you very much for your consideration!

All the best,

A very confused newbie.

Comment: while(test2 = 1) try change it to while(test2 == 1)

Comment: Your while condition should be `test2 == 1`, you missed a `=`.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. Any decent compiler will happily warn about this.

Comment: You are using the incorrect assignment operator in your loop conditional

while(test2 = 1) should be while(test2 == 1)

You are setting it correctly but it then gets assigned a value again in the check instead of being used as a comparison.

Comment: @OP -- Advice -- do not put asterisks (`*`) in the uncommented portions of the code you're posting.  It could be confused for pointers and/or a dereference.  Instead, do something like `// <-- Error here`.

Comment: Omg this is so obvious now that I see it.. Thanks guys! unfortunately I don't have enough reputation in order to mark this question as solved but I will do so in a few minutes.

Comment: `}(while (test2 = 1);` Isn't there a stray `(` before `while`?

Comment: Next time please don't post pictures of text but post text as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your while condition to test2 == 1

test2 = 1 is an assignment, setting the value to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to accept your answer straight away (there is a timer it seems) but it definitely solved my problem. Quite obvious tbh now that I see it. 3h of trouble shooting wasted for this ^^'

Comment: ***3h of trouble shooting wasted for this*** You need to spend 20 minutes and learn how to use a debugger. If you had a debugger and knew how to use it finding a bug like this would take a few minutes not hours.

Comment: I am using Visual studio and I run it in debug mode. However, I have to admit that I have not yet figured out how I use this IDE most effectively. The output did not warn me about this.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you need to learn what the F10, F11 and F9 keys do. These are the most important ones to learn. Effective debugging starts with setting breakpoints and stepping through your code 1 line at a time while looking at the important variables at each step until you see something that does not match your expectations. If you just press the play looking button you are not really getting anywhere near the full benefit from the debugger.